# Load_libs already has been called error while installing hue on redhat?

Tags: bigdata, cloudera, hue

I clone hue from github

I export python version to 3.8 and run make apps

It runs well untill the end but at the end while running hue commands like `...python /build/env/bin/hue --migration`  it gives error

```
loads_libs already has been called
```

If i run manually hue runserver it gives same error

How can i handle this